# Problems export/importing between MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, percona, mariadb

I'm attempting to import an SQL file generated by `5.5.25-MariaDB-mariadb1` into `5.1.55-rel12.6 - (Percona Server (GPL), 12.6 , Revision 200)` after importing the first 11 tables the import process breaks with the following error:-

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 35252: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1' at line 10
```

Line 35252 contains the following:-

```
CREATE TABLE `kygvj_bwps_lockouts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `starttime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `exptime` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `host` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=Aria AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1;
```

Can anyone suggest what the right syntax might be? I have been unable to locate the documentation referred to in the error message.

Comment: `PAGE_CHECKSUM` is not in vanilla MySQL or vanilla Percona server, and should be added by the `Aria` engine. Is that engine available in on your percona server? Depending on why you've set it, omitting it _may_ be an option.

Comment: @Wrikken No - it's a shared hosting solution from mediatemple so I don't really have a choice. Having looked through the file and seen no other instances of PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 I deleted it and that seems to have solved the problem.