# is it possible to convert php mysql version 5.4.42 created database to Php mysql version 5.3.21

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

hi every one,
             i developed a joomla website based on version 2.5 and and i created the database in php mysql version 5.4.42 and i need to load it to the host where they have php mysql version 5.3.21 where i am getting the below mentioned error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gst_update_sites_extensions` (
   `update_site_id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `extension_id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ( `update_site_id` , `extension_id` )
    ) ENGINE = Aria DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM =1 
     COMMENT = 'Links extensions to update sites';
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 COMMENT='Links extensions to update sites'' at line 11

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be moving from a host that used [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/) to one that uses MySQL (and BTW, you gave us versions of PHP and not of MySQL - they're two different things).
Try changing `ENGINE=Aria` to `ENGINE=MyISAM` and remove `PAGE_CHECKSUM =1` part as MyISAM does not support it.

Comment: yes you are correct. Db created mysql version is 5.5.23-MariaDB and the DB in my current hosting is 5.1.69 can you please tell me how to change ENGINE=Aria to engine=MyISAM

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225451/problems-export-importing-between-mysql-versions) has a comment about the fact the server not having Engine Aria since PAGE_CHECKSUM comes from Aria and not from base mysql version. Can you confirm/deny it has it?